# Swagger UI render problem for oneOf for OpenAPI 3.0 specification

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I wrote an OpenAPI 3.0 specification to define an object which has to refer the abstract class whose properties are inherited by two other classes. I used Swagger Codegen CLI to generate the Java code and use the objects for serialization and deserialization and it worked perfectly. Now, in order to demo it, I want to view that on Swagger UI. I used [this tutorial](https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/pubapis_swagger.html) for rendering the UI. However, I have not been able to get the correct rendering. The interesting part is that when I try to refer to the same in an API specification, it works fine.

My YAML specification files are split across multiple folders and they refer to data objects in each through relative path specification.

File locations are something like this:

- File with object trying to use abstract class[whcih doesn't work on UI]: configuration/openapi/v3/submit_request/v1/ExecutionRequest.yaml
- File with abstract class and the inherited class[renders perfectly as well]:
  configuration/openapi/v3/inference/v1/invocation_request.yaml
- File with API definition[which works on UI]:
  configuration/openapi/v3/inference/v1/api.yaml

I have tried:

1. Reading through polymorphism, inheritance articles on the web for help, but nowhere have I found an example where the abstract class has to be used in another object other an API request/response.
2. I have tried various combinations for defining polymorph relation in the object, but they seem to break the codegen.

Object using the abstract class:

```
ExecutionRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        invocationData:
          type: InvocationsRequest
          description: |
            The type of invocation input data that is inputted. The invocation data can be submitted as
            reference or value. 
          oneOf:
            - $ref: "../../inference/v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ReferenceInvocationsRequest"
            - $ref: "../../inference/v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ValueInvocationsRequest"
          discriminator:
            propertyName: dataType
            mapping:
              value: '../../inference/v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ValueInvocationsRequest'
              reference: '../../inference/v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ReferenceInvocationsRequest'
```

Abstract class definition:

```
InvocationsRequest:
      type: object
      description: |
        This is the abstract structure of invocations request. It discriminates based on dataType property.
      properties:
        dataType:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataType'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: dataType
        mapping:
          value: '#/components/schemas/ValueInvocationsRequest'
          reference: '#/components/schemas/ReferenceInvocationsRequest'
```

API definition where it renders correctly

```
post:
      x-amzn-cpp-ai-input-dataType: InvocationsRequest
      x-amzn-cpp-ai-input-paramName: invocationsRequest
      description: This API serves the inference requests.
      requestBody:
        description: Input to the invocations API
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: "../v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ReferenceInvocationsRequest"
                - $ref: "../v1/invocation_request.yaml#/components/schemas/ValueInvocationsRequest"
```

Actual data schema definition:

```
    DataType:
      description: |
        This is an enum denoting how data is being passed to the API. <br/>
        If the actual payload is passed in request then dataType is value.
        If the location of payload is passed in request then dataType is reference.
      type: string
      enum:
        - value
        - reference
    ReferenceInvocationsRequest:
      description: |
        This structure should be used for a reference to a 
        batch of records 
      x-discriminator-value: reference
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/InvocationsRequest'
        - type: object
          properties:
            invocationsDataListRef:
              description: |
                Location of the serialized value of "#/components/schemas/InvocationsDataList"
              type: string
    ValueInvocationsRequest:
      description: |
        This structure should be used when an inline batch of records 
        is passed
      x-discriminator-value: value
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/InvocationsRequest'
        - type: object
          properties:
            invocationsDataList:
              description: |
                Batch of all records provided as input
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/InvocationsData"
    InvocationsData:
      description: Structure containing data
      type: object
      required:
        - dataIdentifier
        - dataList
      properties:
        dataIdentifier:
          description: Unique data identifier
          type: string
        dataList:
          description: List of data-elements.
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Data"
    Data:
      description: Structure representing the data passed in request.
      type: object
      required:
        - namespace
        - data
      properties:
        namespace:
          description: A unique identifier representing the data namespace.
          type: string
        data:
          description: |
            the actual data/location of data.
          type: string
```

UI error screenshot:

[image: Swagger UI model rendering]

One think I can clearly see wrong in the render is the path for the recursive data types. I am not sure why it is taking that though.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you need to replace `type: InvocationsRequest` with `type: object`. The [`type`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#data-types) keyword must be one of the predefined types such as `object`, `array`, `string` etc.

Comment: Can you please also post the schema for `DataType`?

Comment: Hey Helen, Thanks for the reply. I have tried changing the type to object.however with the code generator in that case, it generates the member as object type which than makes POJO creation a little bit complicated. I have posted the schema in the question now.

Comment: What code generator do you use?